# Finding polar form of all solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Write out in polar form all solutions to the the equation
$(x^3 +8)(x^4 −i+1)=0$.

I saw another person asked the same question, but I would like someone to explain to me the $(x^4-i+1)$ part. I do not understand why we would factor out a $\sqrt2$, or how the cos and sin functions get a theta of $3\pi/4$.

I attached a picture of the solution to help.

[solution1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtlOK.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: You want the polar decomposition of $z = -1+i$. So, you need the absolute value $|z|$ and the angle. The absolute value is easily computable and the angle is easily seen when you draw a picture. So, what's the absolute value?

Comment: Would the |z| be the sqrt of 2? Since |z|=sqrt(a^2 + b^2) where a is -1 here and b is 1?

Comment: There you go. Good! Now the angle.